# Hibernate: is it possible to fetch two fields with one join?

Tags: hibernate, join, collections

I have a class `Subject` which has two fields `Collection<Ownership> ownershipFrom` and `Collection<Ownership> ownershipTo`. The `Ownership` class has two fields, `Subject owner` and `Subject owned`

To fetch the Subject with its collections I'm currently doing the following:

`from Subject s left join fetch s.ownershipFrom left join fetch s.ownershipTo`.

This works, but it seems unefficient to me, as I'm accessing the same table (Ownership) twice when, I believe I could access only one time. 
Is there a better way to fetch those classes?

Comment: Are you trying to get the collection of `Ownership` objects that a subject owns or is owned by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start at the `Ownership` object instead of `Subject`. Example:

```
select own
from Ownership own, Subject s
where own.ownershipFrom = s
or own.ownershipTo = s
```

Something along those lines.

Might be useful to check out the following link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html